# Import product image using dataflow profiles

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, dataflow

I want to import product image using dataflow profiles. When upadating the csv file getting an error like 'images not found'.I exported these images from a non-magento database and trying to import using dataflow profile.

Comment: Can you attach csv here for some item as demo . or check /media/import folder . All images must in this folder . and give 777 permission to this folder.

Answer (score 2):

Place the image under `media/import`

then in the CSV use `/productimagename.jpg`

If image contain any folder name then place image in proper folder

Comment: Yes.. I have placed image under `media/import`   then se t` 777 permission` .  In CSV  given image url like ` /productimage.jpg'. But its getting error like `image not found`

Comment: @Sruthi : Does solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

you need to upload all image in media/import with 777 permission and need to define path like below image:

[image]

if you directly add image then it would be same as image but if you have any folder like media/import/products/abc.jpg then path in csv like /products/abc.jpg

Comment: It's not good to apply 777 permission to folder, instead you can use group permission and assign particular group and owner to the folder which will have all the permission. this technique will prevent outside access.

Comment: @YogeshTrivedi
Thank you for explaining in more detail..